# Is there any way to add a default value in html using Thymeleaf?

Tags: html, input, thymeleaf

I'd like to make a form, where I'd like to take the ID of logged in user.
I made a function in my CustomUser to get the ID:

```
public class MyUserDetail implements UserDetails {
   /* default functions */
   public Integer getFullname(){
      return user.getFullName();
   }   

   public Integer getId(){
      return user.getId();
   }
}
```

This way I could get the ID in HTML:

```
<span>[[${#request.userPrincipal.principal.id}]]</span>
```

However, when I tried it in a value of an input, the value was always 0. See the code below:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{'/myObject/save'}" th:object="${myObject}"
            method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User</td>
                    <td th:hidden="false">
                        <input type="number" th:field="*{fk_user}" th:value="${#request.userPrincipal.principal.id}" readonly="readonly">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" th:value="${#request.userPrincipal.principal.fullname}" readonly="readonly">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--- other fields --->
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <button type="submit">Save</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

I also tried it with a simple number `<input type="number" th:field="*{fk_user}" th:value="1" readonly="readonly">`, but it was always 0, too.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is your thymeleaf and spring-security versions?

Comment: Spring: 2.5.2
Thymeleaf: 3.0.12.RELEASE (accoding to `mvn dependency:list -DincludeArtifactIds=thymeleaf`

Comment: You have to either set the `myObject.fk_user` field to the default in your controller, or don't use the `th:field` tag and manually set the `name` and `value` fields yourself.